# How to validate a Timestamp from an ASN.1 encoded byte stream in Java

Tags: java, timestamp, bouncycastle, digital-certificate, asn.1

I'm trying to validate a timestamp from an ASN.1 encoded byte stream in Java.
I'm using the bouncycastle package.

I'm creating the TimeStampToken from the encoded byte I got from the timestampserver.

```
TimeStampToken testTsToken = new TimeStampToken(new CMSSignedData(encodedByte));
```

For validation there is the following function.

```
testTsToken.validate(SignerInformationVerifier);
testTsToken.validate(X509Certificate, String);
```

I'm now wondering how do I get those Parameters?

How can I create a SignerInformationVerifier or a X509Certificate?.

I would appreciate any help because I'm stuck on this issue for days now :/

Answer (score 0):

My problem was that when asking for the timestamp i forgot to ask for a certificate. That's why I couldn't validate.

Comment: It's ok to answer your own question, but it would be helpful to provide a full answer with more detail (in this case, code)

Comment: Well basically I'm using the class  TimeStampRequestGenerator, to generate timestamp requests to a timestampserver, provided by the bouncy class and call the .setCertReq(true) function on it. So I can ask the timestampserver for a certificate. If you don't call this function before the certificate will always be null.